# ¿Cómo manejo los formularios thymeleaf con update jpa?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Estoy tratando de actualizar un registro de la base de datos.
Se tratan de presupuestos de obra. La página dispone de un botón donde ahí muestra el formulario de editar y allí aparecen los datos anteriores y un formulario donde el usuario editará la entidad.

Esta es la página en cuestión

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
<head>
    <title>Editar presupuesto</title>
    <th:block th:insert="~{sections/head.html}"></th:block>
</head>
<body>
    <th:block th:insert="~{sections/header.html}"></th:block>


    <div class="container" >
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title text-center">Editar presupuesto</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h4>Detalles de la solicitud</h4>
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table border="1" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed small">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Cliente</th>
                                    <td th:utext="${presupuestoEdit.cliente.nombre}"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Referencia</th>
                                    <td th:utext="${presupuestoEdit.referencia}"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Datos de la obra</th>
                                    <td th:if="${presupuestoEdit.class.name == 'com.institutmarianao.webtitoproyecto.domain.ObraNueva'}">
                                        Superficie: <span th:utext="${presupuestoEdit.superficie}" th:remove="tag"></span><br>
                                        Calidad: <span th:utext="${presupuestoEdit.calidad}" th:remove="tag"></span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td th:if="${presupuestoEdit.class.name == 'com.institutmarianao.webtitoproyecto.domain.Aseos'}">
                                        Largo: <span th:utext="${presupuestoEdit.largo}" th:remove="tag"></span><br>
                                        Ancho: <span th:utext="${presupuestoEdit.ancho}" th:remove="tag"></span><br>
                                        Alto: <span th:utext="${presupuestoEdit.alto}" th:remove="tag"></span><br>
                                        Precio azulejo por m2: <span th:utext="${presupuestoEdit.precio_azulejo_m2}" th:remove="tag"></span><br>
                                        Modificaci&oacute;n: <span th:utext="${presupuestoEdit.modif_instalacion}" th:remove="tag"></span><br>
                                        Sanitarios (precio): <span th:utext="${presupuestoEdit.num_sanitarios}" th:remove="tag"></span><br>
                                    </td>
                                    <td th:if="${presupuestoEdit.class.name == 'com.institutmarianao.webtitoproyecto.domain.Cocina'}">
                                        Largo: <span th:utext="${presupuestoEdit.largo}" th:remove="tag"></span><br>
                                        Ancho: <span th:utext="${presupuestoEdit.ancho}" th:remove="tag"></span><br>
                                        Alto: <span th:utext="${presupuestoEdit.alto}" th:remove="tag"></span><br>
                                        Precio azulejo por m2: <span th:utext="${presupuestoEdit.precio_azulejo_m2}" th:remove="tag"></span><br>
                                        Modificaci&oacute;n: <span th:utext="${presupuestoEdit.modif_instalacion}" th:remove="tag"></span><br>
                                        Mueble, metros lineales: <span th:utext="${presupuestoEdit.mueble_mtr_lineales}" th:remove="tag"></span><br>
                                        Encimera, metros lineales: <span th:utext="${presupuestoEdit.encimera_mtr_lineales}" th:remove="tag"></span><br>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Total</th>
                                    <td><h4 class="text-center" th:text="${#numbers.formatCurrency(presupuestoEdit.total)}"></h4></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h4>Nuevos datos</h4>
                        <div th:if="${presupuestoEdit.class.name == 'com.institutmarianao.webtitoproyecto.domain.ObraNueva'}">
                            <form th:action="@{'/list/edit/'+${presupuestoEdit.id_presupuesto}}" th:object="${presupuestoEdit}" method="POST">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <p><b>F&oacute;rmula:</b> <br>Superficie total a construir (m2) * 1100€/m2 * Calidad material (baja/media/alta)</p>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Superficie total a construir (m2):</label><br>
                                        <input th:field="*{superficie}" class="form-control" type="number" id="superficie" />
                                    </div>
        
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="calidad">Calidad material:</label><br>
                                        <input th:field="*{calidad}" type="radio" id="baja"  value="0.8">
                                        <label for="baja">Baja</label><br>
                                        <input th:field="*{calidad}" type="radio" id="media"  value="1">
                                        <label for="media">Media</label><br>
                                        <input th:field="*{calidad}" type="radio" id="alta"  value="1.3">
                                        <label for="alta">Alta</label><br>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id_presupuesto}">
                                    
                                    <div class="panel-footer text-center">
                                        <a th:href="@{/list}" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Volver</a>
                                        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit" value="Editar">
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div th:if="${presupuestoEdit.class.name == 'com.institutmarianao.webtitoproyecto.domain.Aseos'}">
                            <form >
                                <fieldset>
                                    <p><b>F&oacute;rmula:</b> <br>2 * (ancho + largo) * alto + (ancho * largo) * 50 + precio_azulejo + (ancho * largo) * 35 + Nº sanitarios + Modificaci&oacute;n instalaciones</p>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                                <label class="panel-title">Dimensiones: (largo X ancho X alto)</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                <label>Largo:</label>
                                                <input th:field="*{presupuestoEdit.largo}" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" id="largo"/><br>
                                                <label>Ancho:</label>
                                                <input th:field="*{presupuestoEdit.ancho}" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" id="ancho"/><br>
                                                <label>Alto:</label>
                                                <input th:field="*{presupuestoEdit.alto}" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" id="alto"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Nº sanitarios:</label><br>
                                        <input th:field="*{presupuestoEdit.num_sanitarios}" type="radio" id="cero" value="0">
                                        <label for="cero">0</label>
                                        <input th:field="*{presupuestoEdit.num_sanitarios}" type="radio" id="uno" value="300">
                                        <label for="uno">1</label>
                                        <input th:field="*{presupuestoEdit.num_sanitarios}" type="radio" id="dos" value="650">
                                        <label for="dos">2</label>
                                        <input th:field="*{presupuestoEdit.num_sanitarios}" type="radio" id="tres" value="800">
                                        <label for="tres">3</label>
                                        <input th:field="*{presupuestoEdit.num_sanitarios}" type="radio" id="cuatro" value="950">
                                        <label for="cuatro">4</label>
                                    </div>
    
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Precio azulejo (€/m2):</label><br>
                                        <input th:field="*{presupuestoEdit.precio_azulejo_m2}" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" id="precio_azulejo" />
                                    </div>
    
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Modificacion instalaciones:</label><br>
                                        <input th:field="*{presupuestoEdit.modif_instalacion}" type="radio" id="ceroM" value="0">
                                        <label for="ceroM">No</label>
                                        <input th:field="*{presupuestoEdit.modif_instalacion}" type="radio" id="unoM" value="225">
                                        <label for="unoM">1</label>
                                        <input th:field="*{presupuestoEdit.modif_instalacion}" type="radio" id="dosM" value="350">
                                        <label for="dosM">2</label>
                                        <input th:field="*{presupuestoEdit.modif_instalacion}" type="radio" id="tresM" value="475">
                                        <label for="tresM">3</label>
                                        <input th:field="*{presupuestoEdit.modif_instalacion}" type="radio" id="cuatroM" value="600">
                                        <label for="cuatroM">4</label>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="panel-footer text-center">
                                        <a th:href="@{/list}" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Volver</a>
                                        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit" value="Editar">
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div th:if="${presupuestoEdit.class.name == 'com.institutmarianao.webtitoproyecto.domain.Cocina'}">
                            <form >
                                <fieldset>
                                    <p><b>F&oacute;rmula:</b> <br>2 * (ancho+largo) * alto + (ancho * largo) * 50 + Precio azulejo + (ancho * largo) * 35 + Muebles, metros lineales + Encimera, metros lineales + Modificaci&oacute;n instalaciones</p>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                                            <label class="panel-title">Dimensiones: (largo X ancho X alto)</label>
                                                        </div>
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                <label>Largo (m):</label>
                                                <input th:field="*{presupuestoEdit.largo}" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" id="largoCocina"/><br>
                                                <label>Ancho (m):</label>
                                                <input th:field="*{presupuestoEdit.ancho}" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" id="anchoCocina"/><br>
                                                <label>Alto:</label>
                                                <input th:field="*{presupuestoEdit.alto}" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" id="altoCocina"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
            
                                                <label>Muebles, metros lineales:</label><br>
                                                <input th:field="*{presupuestoEdit.mueble_mtr_lineales}" class="form-control" type="number" id="muebles"/><br>
            
                                                <label>Encimera, metros lineales:</label><br>
                                                <input th:field="*{presupuestoEdit.encimera_mtr_lineales}" class="form-control" type="number" id="encimera"/><br>
            
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Precio azulejo (€/m2):</label><br>
                                                    <input th:field="*{presupuestoEdit.precio_azulejo_m2}" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" id="precio_azulejo_cocina"/>
                                                </div>
            
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Modificacion instalaciones:</label><br>
                                        <input th:field="*{presupuestoEdit.modif_instalacion}" type="radio" id="milCocina" value="1000">
                                        <label for="milCocina">S&iacute;</label><br>
                                        <input th:field="*{presupuestoEdit.modif_instalacion}" type="radio" id="ceroCocina" value="0">
                                        <label for="ceroCocina">No</label><br>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="panel-footer text-center">
                                        <a th:href="@{/list}" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Volver</a>
                                        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit" value="Editar">
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <th:block th:insert="~{sections/footer.html}"></th:block>
</body>
```

Ahí arriba es donde editaré cada uno de los presupuestos.

Problema? Al guardar esos nuevos datos, me retorna un error 500 donde me pregunta lo siguiente:

Failed to instantiate [com.institutmarianao.webtitoproyecto.domain.Presupuesto]: Is it an abstract class?

Andaba buscando información en internet acerca de qué podría fallar y me he quedado igual. Os muestro un poquito de código que os sirva:

Este es el controller que hace esa acción de actualizar la entidad.

```
// Método para editar presupuesto - GET
    @GetMapping("/list/edit/{id_presupuesto}")
    public String editarPresupuesto(Model model, @PathVariable long id_presupuesto) {
        Presupuesto presupuesto = presupuestoService.findById(id_presupuesto);
    
    if (presupuesto instanceof ObraNueva) {
        ObraNueva obraEdit = obraNuevaService.findById(id_presupuesto);
        model.addAttribute("presupuestoEdit", obraEdit);
    } else if (presupuesto instanceof Aseos) {
        Aseos aseosEdit = aseosService.findById(id_presupuesto);
        model.addAttribute("presupuestoEdit", aseosEdit);
    } else if (presupuesto instanceof Cocina) {
        Cocina cocinaEdit = cocinaService.findById(id_presupuesto);
        model.addAttribute("presupuestoEdit", cocinaEdit);
    }
    
    return "editarPresupuesto";
}

// Método para editar presupuesto - POST
@PostMapping("/list/edit/{id_presupuesto}")
public String editarPostPresupuesto(@ModelAttribute("presupuestoEdit") Presupuesto presupuestoEdit, Model model, @PathVariable long id_presupuesto) {
            
    if (presupuestoEdit instanceof ObraNueva) {
        ObraNueva obraedit = (ObraNueva) presupuestoEdit;
        obraedit.setSuperficie(obraedit.getSuperficie());
        obraedit.setCalidad(obraedit.getCalidad());
        obraedit.setTotal(obraedit.getSuperficie() * ObraNueva.PRECIO_M2 * obraedit.getCalidad());
        obraNuevaService.update(obraedit);
    } else if (presupuestoEdit instanceof Aseos) {
        Aseos aseosedit = (Aseos) presupuestoEdit;
        aseosedit.setLargo(aseosedit.getLargo());
        aseosedit.setAncho(aseosedit.getAncho());
        aseosedit.setAlto(aseosedit.getAlto());
        aseosedit.setPrecio_azulejo_m2(aseosedit.getPrecio_azulejo_m2());
        aseosedit.setModif_instalacion(aseosedit.getModif_instalacion());
        aseosedit.setNum_sanitarios(aseosedit.getNum_sanitarios());
        aseosedit.setTotal(2 * (aseosedit.getLargo() + aseosedit.getAncho()) * aseosedit.getAlto()
                + (aseosedit.getAncho() * aseosedit.getLargo()) * Reforma.MANO_DE_OBRA + aseosedit.getPrecio_azulejo_m2()
                + (aseosedit.getAncho() * aseosedit.getLargo()) * Reforma.PRECIO_M2 + aseosedit.getNum_sanitarios()
                + aseosedit.getModif_instalacion());
        aseosService.update(aseosedit);
        reformaService.update(aseosedit);
    } else if (presupuestoEdit instanceof Cocina) {
        Cocina cocinaedit = (Cocina) presupuestoEdit;
        cocinaedit.setLargo(cocinaedit.getLargo());
        cocinaedit.setAncho(cocinaedit.getAncho());
        cocinaedit.setAlto(cocinaedit.getAlto());
        cocinaedit.setPrecio_azulejo_m2(cocinaedit.getPrecio_azulejo_m2());
        cocinaedit.setModif_instalacion(cocinaedit.getModif_instalacion());
        cocinaedit.setMueble_mtr_lineales(cocinaedit.getMueble_mtr_lineales());
        cocinaedit.setEncimera_mtr_lineales(cocinaedit.getEncimera_mtr_lineales());
        cocinaedit.setTotal(2 * (cocinaedit.getLargo() + cocinaedit.getAncho()) * cocinaedit.getAlto()
                + (cocinaedit.getAncho() * cocinaedit.getLargo()) * Reforma.MANO_DE_OBRA + cocinaedit.getPrecio_azulejo_m2()
                + (cocinaedit.getAncho() * cocinaedit.getLargo()) * Reforma.PRECIO_M2 + (cocinaedit.getMueble_mtr_lineales() * 80)
                + (cocinaedit.getEncimera_mtr_lineales() * 150)
                + cocinaedit.getModif_instalacion());
        cocinaService.save(cocinaedit);
        reformaService.update(cocinaedit);
    }

    presupuestoService.update(presupuestoEdit);
    return "redirect:/list";
}
```

Y luego en el service de Presupuesto, ObraNueva, Aseos, Reforma y Cocina, tengo este método que es el que regula la actualización, es decir, el que tiene la acción de actualizar (no sé si es correcto, diría que si)
Este es:

```
    @Override
public Presupuesto update(Presupuesto presupuestoUpdate) {
    Optional<Presupuesto> updatePresupuesto = presupuestoRepository.findById(presupuestoUpdate.getId_presupuesto());
    Presupuesto update = updatePresupuesto.get();
    return presupuestoRepository.save(update);
}
```

Este es para Presupuesto, cada una de las clases que he indicado que disponen de este método, tienen su update también.

Espero que les sirva para ayudarme, gracias!
Si necesitan algo más de código no duden en pedirlo :)

ACTUALIZACIÓN 1:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="presupuestos")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Presupuesto {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
protected long id_presupuesto;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cliente", referencedColumnName = "id_cliente")
protected Cliente cliente;

protected String referencia;

protected String destinatario;

protected String direccion;

protected String codigoPostal;

protected String municipio;

protected String provincia;

protected String comunidad;

protected String pais;

@Column(name = "fecha", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
protected Date fecha;

protected double total;

public Presupuesto() {
    super();
}

public Presupuesto(long id_presupuesto, Cliente cliente, double total) {
    super();
    this.id_presupuesto = id_presupuesto;
    this.cliente = cliente;
    this.total = total;
}

public Presupuesto(long id_presupuesto, Cliente cliente, String referencia, String destinatario, String direccion,
        String codigoPostal, String municipio, String provincia, String comunidad, String pais, Date fecha, double total) {
    super();
    this.id_presupuesto = id_presupuesto;
    this.cliente = cliente;
    this.referencia = referencia;
    this.destinatario = destinatario;
    this.direccion = direccion;
    this.codigoPostal = codigoPostal;
    this.municipio = municipio;
    this.provincia = provincia;
    this.comunidad = comunidad;
    this.pais = pais;
    this.fecha = fecha;
    this.total = total;
}

public long getId_presupuesto() {
    return id_presupuesto;
}

public void setId_presupuesto(long id_presupuesto) {
    this.id_presupuesto = id_presupuesto;
}

public Cliente getCliente() {
    return cliente;
}

public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
    this.cliente = cliente;
}

public String getReferencia() {
    return referencia;
}

public void setReferencia(String referencia) {
    this.referencia = referencia;
}

public String getDestinatario() {
    return destinatario;
}

public void setDestinatario(String destinatario) {
    this.destinatario = destinatario;
}

public String getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public String getCodigoPostal() {
    return codigoPostal;
}

public void setCodigoPostal(String codigoPostal) {
    this.codigoPostal = codigoPostal;
}

public String getMunicipio() {
    return municipio;
}

public void setMunicipio(String municipio) {
    this.municipio = municipio;
}

public String getProvincia() {
    return provincia;
}

public void setProvincia(String provincia) {
    this.provincia = provincia;
}

public String getComunidad() {
    return comunidad;
}

public void setComunidad(String comunidad) {
    this.comunidad = comunidad;
}

public String getPais() {
    return pais;
}

public void setPais(String pais) {
    this.pais = pais;
}

public Date getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public double getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(double total) {
    this.total = total;
}
    
}
```

Adjunto la clase Presupuesto también

Comment: Hola Ismael, el mensaje **Failed to instantiate blabla Presupuesto]: Is it an abstract class?**, es bastante claro, y no nos das la respuesta, es la clase **Presupuesto** abstracta?.

Comment: Ups, si, se me olvidó especificar la clase :0 :D Actualizo mi pregunta para incorporar la clase

Comment: Ya tienes el problema detectado, al ser abstracta, no puedes instanciarla, por otro lado, he visto que tienes al menos otra clase abstracta, y comparten la caracteristica de no tener ningún método abstracto, lo que no tiene razón de ser, yo eliminaría el "abstracto" de las clases y probaría.

Comment: Hmm entiendo. Aunque existiría una solución siendo esta clase abstracta? Para mi programa lo necesito, puesto que quien genera los pregupuestos son las clases ObraNueva, Cocina y Aseos.

Comment: "La" característica de una clase abstracta, es tener métodos abstractos, la tuya no tiene, no hay motivos para declararla abstracta.

Comment: Okey, ese error ya parece que no me aparece. Ahora viene otro que indica que el id  que le llega es nulo. ¿Cómo le indico al programa que trate el id del objeto a editar?

Comment: Hola Ismael, te sugiero que abras una nueva pregunta, añadiendo en ella, la sección donde instancias la clase **Presupuesto** que es la implicada en el problema que mencionas.